# Jquery ui autocomplete not working in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

**Admin controller**

```
public ViewResult Products()

public PartialViewResult AddProduct()

public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
```

**View**

```
Product.cshtml

AddProduct.cshtml - Partial View
```

I'm loading a partial view(`AddProduct.cshtml`) in modal popup in main view.

In partial view I have a form and I'm trying to add jQuery UI autocomplete on input field but its not working.

```
$(function() {
        $("#txtProductName").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return item;
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

I have added this jquery code in partial view page itself, also when I'm trying to save form data using ajax that too not working

Comment: any errors in the console? anything like 'autocomplete is not a function' or no erros?

Comment: no error i have wrote console.log but its not printing in console, so autocomplete is not triggered

Comment: now i am getting this error in console "Products:1 Uncaught TypeError: autocomplete is not a function  at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Products:1)"

Comment: is jquery-ui file referenced in your main cshtml?

Comment: yes I have included all the js files <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>in _layout.cshtml which is shared view

Comment: So I have solved the issue by the way thanks for helping, just one more thing I have using `$.ajax` to submit the partial view data to the controller so I want to show the error messages when `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is not valid is there any clue how to do this, I am using `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required")]` in my model

Comment: how was the issue fixed?

Comment: and regarding adding validation, there are plenty of resources online. Just Search "ASP.Net MVC validation". This one from microsoft docs is thorogh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: I have added autocomplete code on partial view itself, and added jQuery reference to the _layout shared view and thanks for your time buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue myself.

**Here is my Controller code**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Products() - Listing all the products (used for main view)

[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult AddProduct() - Add new product form (used for partial view)

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix) - Fetching data from database for autocomplete
```

**View**

```
Product.cshtml - Html for listing all the products (Main View)

AddProduct.cshtml - Html for add new product form (Partial View)
```

So I have added all the jQuery refrence in the `_Layout.cshtml` (shared view) file and in partial view I have added the following jQuery code at bottom of the page

```
$("#txtProductName").autocomplete({
    rest of the logic and ajax hit goes here...
}); - used to show autocomplete suggestion when user types

$("#AddNewProduct").on("submit", "#AddNewProductForm", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        rest of the logic goes here...
    });
}); - used to submit the form data
```